# Atomic AddOrUpdate for a C# Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, atomic

Suppose the following code:

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(aKey))
    myDictionary[aKey] = aValue;
else
    myDictionary.Add(aKey, aValue);
```

This code accesses the dictionary two times, once for determining whether `aKey` exist, another time for updating (if exists) or adding (if does not exist). I guess the performance of this method is "acceptable" when this code is executed only a few times. However, in my application similar code is executed roughly 500K times. I profiled my code, and it shows 80% of CPU time spent on this section (see the following figure), so this motivates an improvement.

[image]
Note that, the dictionary is `lambdas`.

**First workaround** is simply:

```
myDictionary[aKey] = aValue;
```

If `aKey` exist it's value is replaced with `aValue`; if does not exist, a `KeyValuePair` with `aKey` as key and `aValue` as value is added to `myDictionary`. However, this method has two drawbacks:

*First*, you don't know if `aKey` exist or not that prevents you from additional logics. For instance, you can not rewrite following code based on this workaround:

```
int addCounter = 0, updateCounter = 0;
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(aKey))
{
    myDictionary[aKey] = aValue;
    addCounter++;
}
else
{
    myDictionary.Add(aKey, aValue);
    updateCounter++;
}
```

*Second*, the update can not be a function of the old value. For instance, you can not do a logic similar to:

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey(aKey))    
    myDictionary[aKey] = (myDictionary[aKey] * 2) + aValue;    
else    
    myDictionary.Add(aKey, aValue);
```

The **second workaround** is to use `ConcurrentDictionary`. It's clear that by using  `delegates` we can solve the *second* aforementioned issue; however, still, it is not clear to me how we can address the *first* issue.

Just to remind you, my concern is to speed up. Given that there is only one thread using this procedure, I don't think the penalty of concurrency (with locks) for only one thread is worth using `ConcurrentDictionary`.

Am I missing a point? does anyone have a better suggestion?

Comment: Just to confirm once more: This is single-threaded, there is no reason for synchronizing access here? So you don’t actually need an *atomic* operation, but just a fast way to set a value and figure out whether you added or updated a value?

Comment: You could check if `Count` of items changed in dictionary after `myDictionary[aKey] = aValue` to get around first drawback.

Comment: First of all, cache designatedRegions[_i] in a loop scoped variable, then, cache designatedRegions[_i].lambdas in another loop scoped variable. Do you see the 4,5% cpu time in designatedRegions[_i].mu-- ? Doing this alone will probably speed you up considerably.

Comment: @poke, yes, this is single-threaded. Atomic in this sense: you traverse a tree for a node, you get to the position that the node is supposed to be there (based on the parent), if the node is there do the update if not do not go back and tell the user it does not exist, just perform addition.

Comment: @OguzOzgul probably I mis-understand you, `mu--` depends on whether the `lambdas` is updated or not; so separate cache may not help much. To clarify, would it be possible for you to give a code example ?

Comment: @ghord, yes, this is possible, but not sure it would be the best.

Comment: @Hamed `Count` is O(1) on dictionary, so it will speed up your code.

Comment: What I mean is, inside your loop, have a variable of type DegisnatedRegion currentRegion = _designatedRegions[_i]; and then, have another variable Dictionary<string, int> currentLambdas = currentRegion.lambdas;     I am not talking about caching, but, locally assigning the objects you work on to variables, to not access them through indexers or property getters. There is a 4.5 % spent only on getting the designated region from the list of designated regions

Comment: @ghord, yes you're right, my point is: your suggestion solves the first issue, but it may not help with the second. am I right ?

Comment: @ghord Checking whether a key exists in a dictionary is O(1) too.

Comment: @OguzOzgul, oh I see your point now. You're right, this could speedup. However, just to clarify, this is not targeting the dictionary issue (since it is the major issue, I focused on it).

Comment: I know that it's not. But it will get you probably a 13,5% improvement for free because your 55% and 27% statements both contain this extra 4.5% right?

Comment: @OguzOzgul, yes, maybe.

Comment: @poke AFAIK it's constant amortized, and it won't be as performant as `Count` due to larger constant factors.

Comment: Some things to be aware of with the `ConcurrentDictionary`, first it does solve the first issue if you use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee378675(v=vs.110).aspx). However if you where in a multi-threaded situation the point may be moot, the delegates that are passed in may get called more than once before the function returns. If two callers both try to add both Add factories can run, but the slower of the two will discard the result then call the update factory. If two try to update at the same time the slower update gets discarded and the factory is called again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want `AddOrUpdate` method like in `ConcurrentDictionary` but without performance implications of using one, you will have to implement such Dictionary yourself.

The good news is that since CoreCLR is open source, you can take actual .Net Dictionary source from [CoreCLR repository](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs) and apply your own modification. It seems it will not be so hard, take a look at the `Insert` private method there.

One possible implementation would be (untested):

```
public void AddOrUpdate(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> adder, Func<TKey, TValue, TValue> updater) {

    if( key == null ) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.key);
    }

    if (buckets == null) Initialize(0);
    int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;

    for (int i = buckets[targetBucket]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next) {
        if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key)) {
            entries[i].value = updater(key, entries[i].value);
            version++;
            return;
        } 

    }
    int index;
    if (freeCount > 0) {
        index = freeList;
        freeList = entries[index].next;
        freeCount--;
    }
    else {
        if (count == entries.Length)
        {
            Resize();
            targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
        }
        index = count;
        count++;
    }

    entries[index].hashCode = hashCode;
    entries[index].next = buckets[targetBucket];
    entries[index].key = key;
    entries[index].value = adder(key);
    buckets[targetBucket] = index;
    version++;

}
```

Comment: I like this, as it seems to be the one and only solution. One additional question: my app is going to be open source with GPLv3, does using this code from Microsoft with MIT license (although with modifications) breaks any rule ?

Comment: @Hamed I'm pretty sure [you can](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4035702/can-i-relicense-someones-mit-code-under-gpl), but I'm not a lawyer ;)

Comment: Since .NET 6 there is a new way to do this, see my other answer

Answer (score 4):

Since **.NET 6** there is a new method [`CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.getvaluereforadddefault) to do just that.

Sample usage:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

ref string? dictionaryValue = ref CollectionsMarshal.GetValueRefOrAddDefault(dictionary, "key", out bool exists);

//variable 'exists' is true if key was present, and false if it had to be added

if (exists)
{
    //Update the value of dictionaryValue variable
    dictionaryValue = dictionaryValue?.ToLowerCaseInvariant();
}
else
{
    //assign new value
    dictionaryValue = "test";
}
```

The only drawback is that you cannot decide not to add the new value after invoking this method. It always creates placeholder empty value in your dictionary if key is missing. You basically have to assign this new value or you are left with an empty entry in your dictionary.