# Extend C# Dictionary for Atomic AddOrUpdate

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, atomic

Previously I asked a question on [Atomic AddOrUpdate on C# Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33732656/atomic-addorupdate-on-c-sharp-dictionary). Basically the answer I got was to extend C# `Dictionary` implementation, which I found it quite rational.

I extended the `Dictionary` implementation as was suggested, however, the performance was surprisingly bad!! Then I tried to minimize my tweaks on C# implementation to trace the cause. The minimum I could reach was: I created an `AddOrUpdate` function, which has a very similar signature to `Add` except it returns `bool` if the dictionary contained the `key` and it's value is updated by given `value`, or false if otherwise. Basically [on this source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs) I made following changes:

```
public bool AddOrUpdate(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    return Insert(key, value);
}
```

and

```
private bool Insert(TKey key, TValue value)
{
    if (buckets == null) Initialize(0);
    int hashCode = comparer.GetHashCode(key) & 0x7FFFFFFF;
    int targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;

    for (int i = buckets[targetBucket]; i >= 0; i = entries[i].next)
    {
        if (entries[i].hashCode == hashCode && comparer.Equals(entries[i].key, key))
        {
            entries[i].value = value;
            version++;
            return true; // on original code, it returns void
        }
    }
    int index;
    if (freeCount > 0)
    {
        index = freeList;
        freeList = entries[index].next;
        freeCount--;
    }
    else {
        if (count == entries.Length)
        {
            Resize();
            targetBucket = hashCode % buckets.Length;
        }
        index = count;
        count++;
    }

    entries[index].hashCode = hashCode;
    entries[index].next = buckets[targetBucket];
    entries[index].key = key;
    entries[index].value = value;
    buckets[targetBucket] = index;
    version++;
    return false; // on original code, does not return anything
}
```

I profiled CPU performance on my code, here are few snapshots (Note: `lambdas` is a dictionary of modified type):

[image: This my code's CPU profile:]

and this is the dictionary code:
[image: Dictionary code]

**Comparison:** initially my code without atomic AddOrUpdate was taking roughly *2min*, but now it does not even finish! while it occupies more than *10GB* of RAM and takes for ever!!

Am I missing a point ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has something to do with that you've removed the setting of the `IEqualityComparer`.

But instead of adapting the Insert method I'd suggest you simply call the original `Insert` with the add flag set to `false` from your `AddOrUpdate` method. Because then the `Insert` basically behaves like an add or update method would.

Comment: `IEqualityComparer` ?! No, I have not changed it. Basically comparer is always provided by `TKey` both in this scenario and the previous.

Comment: Besides, I don't see how `Insert` with a `bool` flag can work as `AddOrUpdate`, at least by returning a `boolean` saying the key is added or updated.

Comment: If you look at the code you'll get it. The insert method first checks in the loop if a key like the one passed into the method exists. If add is set to true it will throw an exception when the same key exists. If it is set to false it will simply set the new value and return.
When the for loop is completed it knows no key like the one provided is present in the dictionary and therefore adds it.

Comment: Ok, it isn't your typical AddOrUpdate since it doesn't return a value. But this isn't needed since you'd only pass a value and know that this will be the one that is stored in the end.
Well then I'm confused. You return after the setting of the version. But after the setting of the version in the original code the private field comparer is set. And the comparer is used for the GetHashCode and Equals operations. It doesn't take the comparer of the TKey unless you set it in some code which is not posted in this question

Comment: First point: `TKey` is a custom object, and implements necessary interfaces, which are used by dictionary. Second point: I double-checked original code, after `version++` is `return`, not a comparer.